# Why does best estimator from RandomizedSearchCV on XGBClassifier gives different results when run separately?

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I am attempting to get best hyperparameters for XGBClassifier that would lead to getting most predictive attributes. I am attempting to use RandomizedSearchCV to iterate and validate through KFold.

I get the best fit estimators and run the predict function on test sub-sample data. Then I look at my confusion matrix and see that I get perfect results, even though my target is missing.

Then I get the best estimator and run XGBClassifier directly, my confusion matrix results drastically change. I am not sure what am I doing wrong as I want the best fit estimators to be consistent if run inside RandomizedSearchCV and outside. Why do I keep getting a perfect score?

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import randint
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,recall_score,accuracy_score,f1_score,roc_auc_score

y = np.asarray(df_comb_clean[target])
df_comb_X = df_comb_clean.drop([target],1)
X = np.asarray(df_comb_X)

clf_xgb = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective = 'binary:logistic')
param_dist = {'n_estimators': stats.randint(150, 1000),
              'learning_rate': stats.uniform(0.01, 0.6),
              'subsample': stats.uniform(0.3, 0.9),
              'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
              'colsample_bytree': stats.uniform(0.5, 0.9),
              'min_child_weight': [1, 2, 3, 4]
             }

numFolds = 5
kfold_5 = cross_validation.KFold(n = len(X), shuffle = True, n_folds = numFolds)

clf = RandomizedSearchCV(clf_xgb, 
                         param_distributions = param_dist,
                         cv = kfold_5,  
                         n_iter = 5, # you want 5 here not 25 if I understand you correctly 
                         scoring = 'roc_auc', 
                         error_score = 0, 
                         verbose = 3, 
                         n_jobs = -1)

clf.fit(X, y)
```

Running the following commands gives mean train and tests scores. Also I want to pull out my best estimator:

```
print "mean_train_score", clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
print "mean_test_score", clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
print clf.best_estimator_
```

Output:

```
mean_train_score [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
mean_test_score [ 0.          0.          0.76425856  0.77198744  0.74225311]
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=0.76920759422068707, gamma=0,
       learning_rate=0.13626591956991532, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=7,
       min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=880, nthread=-1,
       objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True,
       subsample=0.59412792468572662)
```

So next step I want to see how well the best estimator will perform on my sub-sample population and output results into a confusion matrix:

```
y_train = np.asarray(df_train[target])
df_train_X = df_train.drop([target],1)
X_train = np.asarray(df_train_X)

dtrain_predictions = clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_train)
cnf_matrix_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, dtrain_predictions)  
print "train: \n" , cnf_matrix_train

y_test = np.asarray(df_test[target])
df_test_X = df_test.drop([target],1)
X_test = np.asarray(df_test_X)    

dtest_predictions = clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
xpred = pd.DataFrame(dtest_predictions)
cnf_matrix_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, dtest_predictions)  
print "test: \n" , cnf_matrix_test
```

This gives me a very strange output and I am not sure why (I removed target in the above section, even reset indexes):

```
train: 
[[3840    0]
 [   0  354]]
test: 
[[1644    0]
 [   0  150]]
```

Next step I pull out my best estimator and refit/predict it outside of RandomizedSearchCV and now I get same results:

```
clf_best = XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=0.76920759422068707, gamma=0,
       learning_rate=0.13626591956991532, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=7,
       min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=880, nthread=-1,
       objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True,
       subsample=0.59412792468572662)

df_comb_X = df_comb_clean.drop([target],1)
clf_best.fit(df_comb_X, df_comb_clean[target],eval_metric='auc')

clf_test_best= clf_best.predict(df_test_X)

cnf_best_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, clf_test_best)  
print "test: \n" , cnf_best_test

feat_imp = pd.Series(clf_best.booster().get_fscore()).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output on test:

```
test: 
[[1644    0]
 [   0  150]]
```

I figured it out, I was fitting my estimators on the total population and sub-sample was part of the total population. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was fitting XGBClassifier on entire population and then went to randomly sub sample from the same population thus leading to the same results.